# Prismic filters - error 500 when field not available in prismic

Tags: javascript, typescript, filter, content-management-system, prismic.io

I am using the following filter when fetching data from prismic:

```
prismicC.filter.any(`my.alert.page_type.page`, [
      alertData.page,
]),
```

The filter is working as expected only when "my.alert.page_type.page" field is declared in prismic. How can I modify my filter to make it work (fetch the document) if the field is not defined as well?

I am looking for something simillar to:

```
const filters: string[] = [
  prismicC.filter.or([
    prismicC.filter.missing(`my.alert.page_type.page`),
    prismicC.filter.any(`my.alert.page_type.page`, [alertData.page]),
  ]),
];
```

(or filter does not exist in prismic)